# Google Sheets & CF7 Google Sheets Connector - Indirect Cell Reference Issue

Tags: wordpress, google-sheets

I've searched all over the place for something similar to this and have been unable to figure out my issue. I'm guessing it's something with the CF7 Google Sheets Connector plugin and not with the Contact Form 7 plugin, but I'm taking a shot that someone may be able to help here as I've gotten no response on the CF7 Google Sheets Connector plugins' support forum.

Here's the issue quickly. I need to send a hidden formula to a cell in my google sheet.
When I send this from my CF7 form:

[hidden payment-amount default:"=If(X12>0,(65+25*Y12),0)"]

it works fine and my cell is populated with the results of the formula.
The problem is that I need an indirect cell reference for the X12 and Y12 parts because I don't want the value of X12 and Y12. I want the value of the cell in column X and Y for the current row.

My research shows that this should work:

[hidden payment-amount default:"=If(indirect("X" & row())>0,(65+25*indirect("Y" & row())),0)"]

And if I type that formula directly into my cell, it works fine.

However, when I send a form from my website with this as my hidden variable, the target cell is blank.
I think the formula is ok, but something is causing it not to send to the cell or is messing with the formatting or possibly indirect is a reserved word that can't be sent, but I was unable to find documentation listing that it is.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to get these indirect references to send properly to my Google sheet, or a different way to write this formula, that would be awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know if CF7 will have issue with this approach, but if it does not, I would use the formula below in row 1 of the column where you want the formula applied and then there is no need to apply a formula to each cell.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A)=ROW(A1),"My Header",IF(ISBLANK(X1:X),,If(X1:X>0,(65+25*Y1:Y),0))))
```

the ARRAYFORMULA() function let's us work on an array and in this case we are applying a couple formulas to the entire row.  You should recognize your formula in there, so working out from that point

```
IF(ISBLANK(X1:X),,If(X1:X>0,(65+25*Y1:Y),0))
```

Here I am checking to see if there is a value in column X.  If there is not, I return no value. Note that I did not put "" here as in Google Spreadsheets that actually returns a value and can potentially confuse other formulas.  If there is a value (If ISBLANK returns FALSE) then I apply your formula.  This is all wrapped in another IF() function:

```
IF(ROW(A1:A)=ROW(A1),"My Header",IF(ISBLANK(X1:X),,If(X1:X>0,(65+25*Y1:Y),0)))
```

All this does is says If we are in Row A, return "MY Header" to supply a header to the column, otherwise, do the above.

Comment: Thank you Karl! You are awesome! That worked great and I've applied the method to all of my other formulas, but I have one that I can't get to work properly.

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ROW(A1:A)=ROW(A1),"number-divisions-requested",IF(ISBLANK(AJ1:AJ),,10-COUNTBLANK((H1:H):(Q1:Q))))

Comment: COUNTBLANK() is your problem.  ARRAYFORMULA() does not work with other functions which work on an array, such as SUM() an COUNTBLANK().  There are options, such as [the responses in this Google Docs Help Forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/Cb-d7Qf7-Vo/7_FPFWo0sjAJ) which may work but I I start to get that blank stare when one starts adding mmult() with an embedded transpose().  Mark the post answered if the above answered your original question to help others in the future!

Comment: Sorry, I tried to add this to my previous comment but I was too slow:

I need this formula above to return the number of cells between Column H and Column Q of the current row that contain data. Since there are ten cells, subtracting the number of blank cells from 10 should work. I've tried several things but can't get it to return the correct result.

=10-COUNTBLANK(H3:Q3) this works for row 3, so I've tried to apply your method to this formula.

Comment: I would create a new post asking about this specifically and provide a sample spreadsheet if you can.  I think I understand your question, but you are better served with a new post. Including a sample file is always helpful and gets you better responses as well.

Comment: Thanks Karl! I got a blank stare from that mmult stuff too. 
I found an additional solution because I was also having formatting issues when CF7 added new rows to my sheet. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/dlW6U6cHuKw
basically this solution uses an additional sheet that pulls all the data from the original sheet populated by CF7 with arrayformulas. This allows for formatting to be retained on new data. It also allowed me to use my COUNTBLANK() formula without having to put it into an ARRAYFORMULA and just use direct cell references and copy and paste it to a whole column.